# PS file is not well included using latex->dvips chain

Tags: graphics, eps, dvips

I'm trying to include given PostScript files in my document. However, I'm not really successful using the `latex -> dvips` chain as the image is not well included:

[image: latex dvips example]

However, the same file works fine when using `XeTeX`:

[image: xetex sample]

Used image: [Get it here](http://www.x-linux.de/stackoverflow/Reflection_and_Refraction_2D.ps)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
% \fbox to visualize the dimensions  
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Reflection_and_Refraction_2D.ps}}
\end{document}
```

**What do I have to do to get a proper ps-output file?**

I would like to use XeTeX overall, but the output file has to be a PostScript file and pdf2ps does not seem to produce vector output.

Comment: But it is a `.ps`file, anot an `.eps` one!

Answer (score 4):

The bounding box in the ps file is wrong:

```
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 460 77
```

The correct one is:

```
%%BoundingBox: 72 -5 127 4
```

The is the reason why you cannot insert the ps file. Converting it to pdf (what `xetex` internally does) or to eps with a following correcting the bounding box with for example:

```
epstool --bbox --copy  <file>.eps <file>-new.eps
```

or with a correct bb:

```
\fbox{\includegraphics[bb=72 -5 127 4,width=\textwidth]{Reflection_and_Refraction_2D.ps}}
```

If it needs addtional rotating and/or reflecting use

```
\fbox{\reflectbox{\includegraphics[bb=72 -5 127 4,angle=180,width=\textwidth]{<file>.ps}}}
```

Comment: I'm wondering why the bounding box is wrong, as they have been created some while ago using `pstricks + latex -> dvips`. However, I get the warning `Input file "....ps" is not EPSF.` This is obviously true.

Comment: `epstool` needs an eps! You have to convert it first. The bounding box in a ps file is the same as the used paper dimensions and not the one of a image size!

Comment: Okay, converting it with `ps2eps` together with your solution works in principle, but the boundingbox is sometimes too large. In addition, as you have already said, the pictures are upside down. Overall I think that I will have to look into the question "How to get a proper PS from XeTeX" to get to where I wanna go.

Comment: The question is more: Why do you want to use a PS file and not PDF or EPS??

Comment: I have to hand in a proceeding as PostScript file. No other option given. I do not make the rules. I found that the CUPS PostScript driver does a fairly good job in converting from PDF to PS, but however, it is still not perfect.

Comment: using `pdftops` with the created pdf document should be enough.

Comment: This produced huge ps files (10MB) with ugly fonts as pages that include graphics are poorly rastered.